# Is cheap pure silicon going to save the world?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, engineering

A scientist develops a process that can extract the Si out of any compound that contains it ten thousand times cheaper than the current processes. He released his invention for free without patenting it, causing turmoil all over the world.

I need help checking if these industries are affected (and only those), and how.

1. The semiconductor industry now has one of its base materials for free. Instead of paying $100 per ounce of hyperpure silicon, it can be bought now for a penny.
2. Now anyone can obtain silicon from dirt or rocks. Is it a good building material?
3. There's SiO<sub>2</sub> in space. Would it trigger a new space race now that oxygen is easily obtained from the moon or asteroids?

---

Restricting to the three industries to restrict scope.

Comment: You are asking a different phrasing of "what are the consequences of X on society?", which is always too broad.

Comment: My new hobby will be to moon people in all those new, cheap glass houses.

Comment: @user535733 glass is not pure silicon

Comment: The silicon part of a Pentium is something like 2 grams. That is, something like 2 dollars or 3 dollars of silicon. (Hey, the dollar sign turns on/off equations in comments.) Or something in the ball-park of 1 percent the cost of the processor. I don't think "free silicon" is going to stun the microprocessor industry.

Comment: Getting the oxygen out is going to require energy. You can get it out for just slightly above the cost of producing the energy using methods that exist right now.

Comment: Silicon, even ultrapure, is useless if it is not in the right form. In particular, what the semiconductor industry actually uses is wafers (= slices) of monocrystalline silicon; the wafers or slices need to be cut in a very precise orientation with respect to the crystal lattice of the [*boule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boule_(crystal)) of silicon crystal. In the end, by reducing the cost of pure silicon to zero, what you have done is reduce the price of a typical processor (say, a 6-core Intel Coffee Lake Core i5 9400F) from about 150 USD to about 149 USD. Not exactly Earth-shattering.

Comment: The adult film industry will be "booming."

Comment: @L.Dutch Are these modifications enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No effect on microchips. Silicon wafer is not a major contributor to cost of microchips:
   https://virginiasemi.wordpress.com/2017/08/20/how-much-does-a-silicon-wafer-cost/
   It looks like $10 per chip. The amount of silicon in semiconductors is tiny. The bulk of the cost is getting the atoms-sized semiconductors and circuits onto the chip, as well as developing chip designs in the first place.
2. No effect on construction. Pure silicon is very brittle. It will need to be combined with other chemicals or materials to serve as construction material. And it will be replacing bricks, which are already pretty cheap. On the other side, if you can reverse the process and easily create SiO2, you can 3d-print granite structures, and that will be very useful.
3. Space application is interesting, you will get free oxygen on Moon and Mars and other rocky planets, and it can help you make underground dwellings. It will not help you get to the planet, though.
4. Cutting rock: Since quartz is silica, you can use your device to cut through rock. Lots more tunnels, and cave dwellings, and fancy art. Which is nice to have but not revolutionary. You could replace concrete or bricks with shaped quartz, but cost of hauling it from mountains (or deep underground) to cities will be same or higher as for conventional construction materials.
5. Military/terrorist applications: Concrete and brick are mostly silica. Easy way to destroy them will have large consequences. And yes, somebody will think of it. But fear not, it will take a few years to shield/coat/rebuild everything with steel.

Comment: Re cutting rock, not if your local rock happens to be limestone, or any of a number of other rocks with no silicon content.  Also pure quartz is fairly rare, and (in my experience at least) often full of fractures.  Cutting granite might be easier, but it's not all that hard these days, as witness any number of granite countertops &c.